# Why is pandas data frame interpreting all data as NaN?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I am importing data from a csv file for use in a pandas data frame. My data file has 102 rows and 5 columns, and all of them are clearly labelled as 'Number' in Excel. My code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('uni.csv', header=None, names = ['TopThird', 'Oxbridge', 'Russell', 'Other', 'Low'])

print data.head()
```

The output looks like this:

```
            TopThird  Oxbridge  Russell  Other  Low
0  14\t1\t12\t35\t1       NaN      NaN    NaN  NaN
1   14\t1\t12\t32\t0       NaN      NaN    NaN  NaN
2   16\t0\t13\t33\t0       NaN      NaN    NaN  NaN
3    10\t0\t9\t44\t1       NaN      NaN    NaN  NaN
4   18\t1\t13\t28\t1       NaN      NaN    NaN  NaN
```

And this continues to the bottom of the data frame. I have attempted to change the cell type in Excel to 'General' or use decimal points on the 'Number' type, but this has not changed anything.

Why is this happening? How can it be prevented?

Comment: because you haven't passed the right separator. Add a parameter `delim_whitespace=True` to `read_csv`.

Comment: Alternatively, as a TSV, you can use `pd.read_fwf(...)`.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thanks, first one works. Feel free to post as an answer if you want to include some explanation with it.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: wait, what?  As a tab-separated file you're recommending first to use all whitespace as a delimiter, and then to use a fixed-width format reader?

Comment: @DSM Because I'm not sure what would work, I gave two alternatives. One of them seemed to work.

Comment: As a side point, I just noticed that the first line of the data frame is shifted to the left. Do you know how to prevent this?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ the second suggestion doesn't work

Comment: @user7490953 If you have a TSV, I think (inferring from DSM's interjection), that `sep='\t'` would be better than `delim_whitespace`. As for the left being shifted, could it be that you have leading spaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your file is a file of *tab separated values*. You'll need to explicitly let `read_csv` know that it is dealing with whitespace characters as delimiters.

In most cases, passing `sep='\t'` should work.

```
df = pd.read_csv('uni.csv', 
                 sep='\t', 
                 header=None, 
                 names=['TopThird', 'Oxbridge', 'Russell', 'Other', 'Low'])
```

In some cases, however, columns are not perfectly tab separated. Assuming you have a TSV of numbers, it should be alright to use `delim_whitespace=True` -

```
df = pd.read_csv('uni.csv', 
                 delim_whitespace=True, 
                 header=None, 
                 names=['TopThird', 'Oxbridge', 'Russell', 'Other', 'Low'])
```

Which is equivalent to `sep='\s+'`, and is a little more generalised, use with caution. On the upside, if your columns have stray whitespaces, this should take care of that automatically.

---

As mentioned by @Vaishali, there's an alternative function `pd.read_table` that is useful for width TSV files, and will work with the same arguments that you passed to `read_csv` -

```
df = pd.read_table('uni.csv', header=None, names=[...])
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like tab delimited data. Try  `sep='\t'`

```
data = pd.read_csv('uni.csv', sep='\t', header=None, names = ['TopThird', 'Oxbridge', 'Russell', 'Other', 'Low'])
```